# Find if cells in multiple cell ranges in Excel are blank or filled

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a template which others need to fill in. There are some cells which are required, and I'd like to find a way of showing in another column whether the cells have been filled in or not.

Let's say that someone's filling in row D, then the required cells are D4:H4, J4:L4, N4:P4. These cells have various types of data validation requirements applied (dates, text, numbers, drop-down list).

I'd like to show with a "✓" in B4 whether the required cells are filled in or not. A bonus would be if any required cells which are not filled in, could be highlighted, but this isn't strictly necessary.

I've tried various combinations of sumproducts, ifs, isblank, and count, and the best result I've gotten from =(SUMPRODUCT(--ISBLANK(D4:H4))<>ROWS(D4:H4)), however this only covers one of the required ranges. Somehow it also returns "FALSE" only when 4 of the cells are filled, but return "TRUE" when 1, 2, 3, or 5 of the cells are filled...

Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like the below i Cell B4, and change the font to wingdings2

```
=IF(AND(D4<>"",D5<>"",list other cells here etc.),"P","O")
```

For the second part, to highlight anything that is blank create a conditional format with the rule

```
=D4=""
```